# (A)Telicity & Events

Tags: semantics, verbs, lexical-semantics, aktionsart

Dowty's (1979) classified predicates into:

```
1. States 'the woord is burning' ---Atelic
2. Activities 'Mary pushed the cart' ---Atelic
3. Accomplishments 'Mary melted the chocolate' ---Telic 
4. Achievements 'Mary crossed the finish line' ---Telic
```

My question in relation to Dowty's classification is how the atelic/telic diagnostics are configured, are there tests? Or simply they are based on aspect?
I believe that the answer to the second question if indeed this is based on aspect properties (Aktionsart), it would not reveal why sometimes even during the Perfective/past [Finished Action] some predicates are atelic like in 2.
I have read in Borer (2005b) 'the normal course of events' on page 52, that there are some 'truth conditional tests' used to determine atelicity/telicity. But still the picture is always blurry for me. Could anyone here explain this please. Thank you.

NB: I'm not sure about the atelicity of (1), I was only assuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found my old notes from grad school. It's not quite clear if your interest in telicity is historical (e.g. how did Dowty 19XX understand telicity?); obviously, a lot has been done since then.

The following is based on Depraetere 1996.

**Tests to distinguish boundedness from unboundedness and telicity from atelicity**

(15a) John drank beer. (atelic, unbounded)

(15b) John drank a glass of beer. (telic, bounded)

> **Test 1.**
>
> Bounded – “how long does it take X to X?”
>
> Unbounded – “for how long?”

How long did it take John to drink a glass of beer? John drank a glass of beer in half an hour. BOUNDED

For how long did John drink beer? John drank beer for half an hour. (caveat: the answer becomes bounded due to a for-adverbial insertion). UNBOUNDED

“A non-progressive atelic sentence does not allow the use of an in-adverbial (17a), whereas a non-progressive telic sentence does (17b):

(17a) I lived with her for two years/*in a year.

(17b) I did the exercise in 10 minutes.

**Limitations of the test:**

a.  certain sentences can collocate with a for-adverbial as well as with an in-adverbial (zero-telic verbs):

(18a) I mowed the lawn in half an hour. TELIC

(18b) I mowed the lawn for half an hour, then my brother took over. ATELIC

b.  the test can only be used for (a)telicity if the sentence is non-progressive, as progressive telic sentences do not collocate with an in-adverbial:

(19a) ?? He was pushing the cart into the barn in 15 minutes.

A for-adverbial is acceptable in this context but it has the effect of turning a telic sentence into an atelic one (cf. example 18b):

(19b) He was pushing the cart into the barn for 15 minutes.

c.  might be problematic with non-progressive telic punctual situations; use ‘in one second’ instead:

(20a). The bomb exploded in one second.

d.  not useful in sentences already containing a duration adverbial;

> **TEST 2.**
>
> Unbounded – homogeneous situations, i.e. the situation remains the same throughout the time it holds. (subinterval property)
>
> Bounded – heterogeneous situations, “they cannot be broken down into smaller entities that can be indicated with the same name” (Declerck 1991: 264)

(15a) John drank beer. (atelic, unbounded)

(15b) John drank a glass of beer. (telic, bounded)

Note: applicable to (a)telic propositions only and not actual progressive sentences.

> **TEST 3.**
>
> Stop+V-ing (atelic)
>
> Finish+V-ing (telic)

John stopped drinking beer. (atelic)

John finished drinking a glass of beer. (telic)

> **TEST 4.**
>
> If one was verb-ing but was interrupted while verb-ing, has one verb-ed? If the answer is possible – atelic.

If John was drinking beer and he stopped drinking beer, has he drunk beer? Yes. (atelic)

If John was drinking a glass of beer and he stopped drinking a glass of beer, has he drunk a glass of beer? Not necessarily. (telic)

Depraetere, I. (1996). The tense system in English relative clauses: A corpus-based analysis. Berlin; New York: Mouton de Gruyter.

Comment: Dear Alex, thank you for this useful and summarized answer. Now at least I know how the logic works (though still need to learn a lot). If you don't mind I have another last question. Since we consider atelicity & telicity (or unboundedness & boundedness) as a property of Aktionsart (Lexical aspect) that a verb or predicate determines, can we say that these properties don't vary according to voice alternation? Or do they indeed vary? thank you again!